# Change desktop icons alignment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, icons, alignment, desktop

I want to make a app to change the alignment or position of desktop icons.

The problem is I don't know anything of how I can start doing this...

I've searched information and I find the desktop icons position is stored in this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop\ItemPos
```

But it's a large binary value, so what I need to do with that if I want to change the default desktop icon alignment (top-left to down) to top-right to down?

Thankyou for read.

Comment: This is a "I want to solve world hunger" question.  I don't have any idea how to get started on that either.  There is no api that lets you do this, explicitly because Microsoft doesn't want you to mess with the user's icons.  So don't, this question has no answer, you can't solve world hunger.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but exists many applications that can change the position of the icons, for example "Fences" of Stardock, and many others that i can't remember the name... the idea isn't impossible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you may use the SystemParametersInfo function from the  user32 Windows Library.
You may read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Icon
There are a lot of Accessibility parameters about icon\desktop setting.